# Prevent violating of UNIQUE constraint with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, unique-key

I have a table like `(id INTEGER, sometext VARCHAR(255), ....)` with `id` as the primary key and a UNIQUE constraint on `sometext`. It gets used in a web server, where a request needs to find the `id` corresponding to a given `sometext` if it exists, otherwise a new row gets inserted.

This is the only operation on this table. There are no updates and no other operations on this table. Its sole purpose is to persistently number of encountered values of `sometext`. This means that I can't drop the `id` and use `sometext` as the PK.

I do the following:

- First, I consult my own cache in order to avoid any DB access. Nearly always, this works and I'm done.
- Otherwise, I use Hibernate Criteria to find the row by `sometext`. Usually, this works and again, I'm done.
- Otherwise, I need to insert a new row.

This works fine, except when there are two overlapping requests with the same `sometext`. Then an `ConstraintViolationException` results. I'd need something like `INSERT IGNORE` or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` (Mysql syntax) or [MERGE](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-merge.html) (Firebird syntax).

I wonder what are the options?

AFAIK Hibernate `merge` works on PK only, so it's inappropriate. I guess, a native query might help or not, as it may or may not be committed when the second INSERT takes place.

Comment: I don't understand why you cannot use sometext as the PK.

Comment: Also, why cannot you just catch the ConstraintViolationException (and ignore it)?

Comment: @Thilo 1. Because I need a number instead of the text. That's why I use the `id`. Maybe I could use `sometext` and store the number in another column (I could guarantee uniqueness by some other means). +++ 2. I could if I knew that it's not caused by something else. But the table name is not available in the exception. Moreover, it happens in `SessionImpl.flush` (rather than in the INSERT), which most probably means that nothing gets stored.

Comment: Re:2 So you are doing other things in the same transaction? Is that necessary?

Comment: @Thilo Sure, actually the other things are important and this numbering is not. I'm using a single transaction per web request, maybe I could use another one for this. And maybe I could do just a flush and retry on error (this numbering always happens before the real work).

Comment: Or just run the numbering under `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` to have it run in its own separate transaction.

Comment: @Thilo I'm not using JPA nor Spring, but I got the idea. Sure, I can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just let the database handle the concurrency.  Start a secondary transaction purely for inserting the new row.  if it fails with a ConstraintViolationException, just roll that transaction back and read the new row.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this scales well if the likelihood of a duplicate is high, a lot of extra work if some percent (depends on database) of transactions have to fail the insert and then reselect.

A secondary transaction minimizes the length of time the transaction to add the new text takes, assuming the database supports it correctly, it might be possible for the thread 1 transaction to cause the thread 2 select/insert to hang until the thread 1 transaction is committed or rolled back.  Overall database design might also affect transaction throughput.

I don't necessarily question why sometext can't be a PK, wondering why you need to break it out at all.  Of course, large volumes might substantially save space if sometext records are large, it almost seems like you're trying to emulate a lucene index to give you a complete list of text values.

Comment: I'm not concerned about performance here, as nearly everything gets covered by the cache and duplicates will be very rare. FYI I'm numbering the request host addresses. They're rather short, so I don't need to save space, but I want to keep their list in the DB, too. A duplicate happens only when there are two simultaneous request from a *new* client (or two clients sharing an IP), which probably won't ever happen except when testing.